# Twitter Streaming API with GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, twitter

Recently i keep on trying with differences methods on how to consume Twitter Streaming API. The purpose i need so is not the oath but i need to perform keyword search and get the public tweets and its information only. My environment is Google AppEngine + Python 2.7 which is not really allow third party library.

What i tried but it seem outdated and these code are applicable for Python console only.

[Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)

[Tweepy-AppEngine](https://github.com/gumptionthomas/tweepy-appengine)

[Python Twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/)

I failed to do make it work on Google App Engine environment while most of the resources available are 3 years back, and most of them are not make for GAE. Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweepy works fine on AppEngine. Be sure to include the tweepy library into your appengine app's root directory (this negates the 'which is not really allow third party library').

I'de like to provide more insight, but I'm not sure what task you're unable to fulfill with the libraries stated above; is something failing when you're fetching from the Streaming API? Tweepy has support for interfacing with the Streaming API - it's worth looking at https://github.com/gumptionthomas/tweepy-appengine/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py

Don't know if this is helpful at all -- but if you're interested in looking at a GAE + Twitter setup, I have published a twitterbot (that's powered by Google Analytics -- but you can ignore that part) on github: https://github.com/nirvanatikku/ga_twitterbot.

Comment: First.. Thanks for reply :) I guess i need some guide on how to deal with the tweepy, because there're not much tuts available. I'm looking into your awesome Tbot and hope to got some clue from there :)

Comment: I haven't played with the streaming API so I'm not entirely sure if it'll be all that helpful (it will show you how to get things setup, though). If you still have trouble, let me know and I'll try to play with the streaming API when I get some time.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and really really appreciate it :) Do you got any idea on how to perform search (with giving some keywords) and get the latest tweets from public (while in my idea stream API is the latest feeds)

Comment: so.. tweepy has a 'search' method, that results a list of SearchResult objects. This code seems to work fine: (formatting sucks..) 

results = api.search({'q':'[some query]'})
for result in results:
     print getattr(result,'text').encode('utf-8')

Comment: just a couple of follow ups, under the hood the search method is calling: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets, as can be seen at: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py, and the response can be determined by looking at https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py

Comment: i noticed one thing.. it's not live like what i got on monitter.com is this probably caused by the way we use?

Comment: Sweet, glad you got it working! wrt 'live' -- yeah; if you want a firehose like that, you can refer to the streaming example (what you were referring to originally -- the Streaming API): https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py

Comment: Do you have any quick example of how to call the "firehose"?

Comment: Here is the link to new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494687/search-twitter-feeds-with-tweepy-streaming-api

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the Twitter Streaming API from Google App Engine.

GAE doesn't support listen sockets, only [outbound sockets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/). You'll have to use another service, like Google Compute Engine, Heroku, or AWS, or find a way to use the the Twitter REST APIs instead.