# Search twitter feeds with Tweepy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, tweepy

Thanks to @Nirvana Tikku, he solved my question on how to talk with Tweepy and perform simple search in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482572/twitter-streaming-api-with-gae-python). The below are a series of code summary on how i authenticate my tweepy on GAE.

```
import tweepy

creds = json.loads(open('credential.json').read())
tw_consumer_key = creds['tw_consumer_key']
tw_consumer_secret = creds['tw_consumer_secret']
tw_access_token = creds['tw_access_token']
tw_access_token_secret = creds['tw_access_token_secret']

try:
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(tw_consumer_key, tw_consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(tw_access_token, tw_access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
except Exception:
    print "Tweepy Error"
    service = None
    api = None
```

I have a question after success authenticate the tweepy and could have a talk with it. I need to implement the streaming API to get LIVE feeds from twitter. Is anyone here could give me a guide on how to implement the "firehose"? some sample code, please. Thanks

Comment: @Nirvana Tikku , Here is my new question couldn't solve :( Thanks again :)

Comment: hey SLim -- did you ever get this working?

Comment: @NirvanaTikku, Thanks for follow up :) appreciate it!! I can't get streaming working with GAE as they said GAE environment don't allow :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Streaming API with GAE Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482572/twitter-streaming-api-with-gae-python)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from a similar question in the Tweepy forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tweepy/BLSRYzG1Tps

Quoting *steveobd* there:
"GAE doesn't support listen sockets only outbound sockets (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/).  You'll have to use Google Compute Engine or Heroku or similar."